# AngularJs + MVC: How to populate page view from a clicked link in shared layout view?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to AngularJs & working on a test project using AngularJs + MVC, so apologies if this code looks very botched.

I'm trying to figure out how to make a clicked link in my shared view pass over to my index.cshtml view, in a manner that my index view will know which link was clicked.  Ideally, I'd like to do this with angular, so it's seamless.  In my MVC project, I created a shared view for my website template.  Within this template, is a dropdown, populated via AngularJs after retrieving values from my database.  The dropdown contains links on each item within the dropdown.  When a user clicks one of the dropdown links, I want to pass the call seamlessly to my index.cshtml view, but I'm not sure on the best way to do this.

Here's the code I have so far, which is retrieving all dropdown values from the database & populating them in my dropdown on my shared view template.  This works fine, but now I'm unsure of what to do when a user clicks a link within the dropdown.  What I need to happen, is for the table data on my index view to change, based on which link the user clicks in the dropdown.

In my shared view, I'm populating my dropdown values (campaign.Campaign1) via Angular.  "SelectedCampaign" is just text of the campaign name that the user's currently selected:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
     <div class="btn-group" ng-controller="menuController">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{SelectedCampaign}}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="caret"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
                   <a href="#">{{campaign.Campaign1}}</a>
              </li>                                 
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In my Angular MenuController.js script, I'm calling an MVC controller called "GetCampaigns", then returning the result to my shared view's dropdown:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp', [])
.controller('menuController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Account/GetCampaigns')
        .success(function (result) {
                $scope.SelectedCampaign = result[0]['Campaign1'];
                $scope.campaigns = result;                
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
})
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the "a" link use ng-click and use the ng-click directive to update the current data to the selected campaign data. So put all the campaigns on your scope, then use the ng-click to call a function to select the campaign.  Something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
               <span ng-click="selectCampaign($index)">{{campaign.Campaign1}}</span>
          </li>
```

You can use $index to get the index in the repeat and use that to target the item in the array:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

e.g.

```
$scope.selectCampaign = function(index){
   $scope.selectedCampaign = $scope.campaigns[index];
}
```